# checking if statemend about Character in String JAVA

Tags: java, if-statement, character

I have a little problem that I cannot understand ,
why this code underline on red the "UsernameValidation" which say that this must return a String
I've return string but its not count for some reason
Thanks for help

```
public static String UsernameValidation(String str){ 
  if ((str.length()>20 || (str.length()<3))){
      if(str.endsWith("_")){
          if(Character.isDigit(str.charAt(0))){
            str = "False";
            return str;
          }else{
              str = "True";
              return str;
          }
       }
  }
```

}

Comment: If your if-statements are not matched, you don't execute any return statement. Your method must return a string (or throw an exception) in all circumstances.

Comment: @khelwood so I am actually contradict myself somewhere in the if-statments?

Comment: If your string is shorter than 3 or longer than 20 or does not end in `_`, what should the method return? You do not indicate that anywhere.

Comment: @Niv you haven't return String in case of first if statement false.

Comment: I am tried try/catch and to make else for the first if-statment but no luck , Im surely think that I'am dont 100% understand you beacuse I still get this error

Comment: @Niv I'm not sure where you got the idea that try/catch would help here because no one mentioned it. Your problem is that your method must return a value for every path it can take. But what if your first `if ((str.length()>20 || (str.length()<3)))` isn't entered at all? Your method does not return anything in that case. The same is true for `if(str.endsWith("_"))`. You must make sure that the method alway returns something. An easy way to do this would be to just add `return "SomeDefaultValue";` at the end of your method that will get reached if npo other return is reached before.

Comment: And on a slightly unrelated note: Having a method return  the Strings `"True"` and `"False"` looks like really bad design. If you want your method to return a true/false value then this is what the data type `boolean`/`Boolean` is for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Provided valid names are those that do not start with a digit, do not end with underscore and are between 3 and 20 characters long:
You should not nest your if-else blocks, but instead check each creterium in its own block:

```
public static String UsernameValidation(String str){ 
   if (str.length() < 3 || str.length() > 20){
       return "False";
   }
   else if(str.endsWith("_")){
       return "False";
   }
   else if(Character.isDigit(str.charAt(0))){
       return "False";
   }
   else{
       return "True";
   }
}
```

You could also combine all conditions that lead to an invalid name with or and save a few lines:

```
public static String UsernameValidation_2(String str){ 
   if (str.length() < 3 || str.length() > 20 || str.endsWith("_") || Character.isDigit(str.charAt(0))){
       return "False";
   }
   else{
       return "True";
   }
}
```

But you could also take a regex approach and write it again more compactly:

```
public static String UsernameValidation_3(String str) {
    return str.matches("[^0-9].{1,18}[^_]") ? "True" : "False";
}
```

Comment: Worked ... Thanks everyone..Ive understand the mistake but I cant really make it work with the fixes I tried. however , now it worked with the else-if

Answer (score -1):

```
    public static String UsernameValidation(String str){ 
      if ((str.length()>20 || (str.length()<3))){
          if(str.endsWith("_")){
              if(Character.isDigit(str.charAt(0))){
                str = "False";
                return str;
              }else{
                  str = "True";
                  return str;
              }
           }
**else
 return something;**
      }
```

You are missing else part.

Comment: well, its still doesnt work for some reason , I copy paste this and same error

Comment: This won't compile. It doesn't have a return for every path.